# How do I consolidate these two subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, code-cleanup

I am writing an e-commerce query that polls for users with specific roles.  The exact purpose of the query isn't important, all that matters is that it's working as intended right now.  However, I really would like to clean up this section of the query

```
.
.
.
where u.firstname is not null
and u.users_id in (
  select u.users_id from users u 
  inner join mbrrole mr on mr.member_id = u.users_id and mr.ORGENTITY_ID IN (
      select ORGENTITY_ID from po_org_tree_v
  )
  inner join roledesc rd on rd.role_id = mr.role_id 
  where 1=1 
  and rd.displayname IN ('Customer Service Representative',  'Account Representative')
) 
and u.users_id in (
  select u.users_id from users u 
  inner join mbrrole mr on mr.member_id = u.users_id and mr.ORGENTITY_ID IN (
      select ORGENTITY_ID from po_org_tree_v
  )
  inner join roledesc rd on rd.role_id = mr.role_id 
  where 1=1 
  and rd.displayname = 'Registered Customer'
);
```

As you can see, I have to nearly identical subqueries in the parent query's where clauses, where the only difference between then is the rd.displayname check.  Is there some way in sql to comine two like queries into a "function", similar to actual functions in programming languages?  How can I combine these subqueries to clean up the main query?

Comment: `WHERE 1 = 1` the `1 = 1` part is useless so you can clean that up already

Comment: No you can't use a function because a function can't return records..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is checking that two different types of roles are available for each user.

Your current method might have the best performance, but you can simplify this down to one subquery:

```
where u.firstname is not null and
      u.users_id in (select mr.member_id
                     from mbrrole mr inner join
                          roledesc rd
                          on rd.role_id = mr.role_id
                     where mr.ORGENTITY_ID IN (select ORGENTITY_ID from po_org_tree_v) and
                           rd.displayname IN ('Registered Customer', 'Customer Service Representative',  'Account Representative')
                     group by mr.member_id
                     having sum(rd.displayname = 'Registered Customer') > 0 and
                            sum(rd.displayname IN ('Customer Service Representative',  'Account Representative')) > 0
                    )
```

Note the following changes:

- Removed `users` from the subquery.  It is not needed.
- Moved the `ORGENTITY_ID` condition to the `where` clause.
- Added the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.  The `HAVING` checks that both types of roles are defined for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) to help you!

You'll need to use a procedure and not a function to return a result set so something like this should work (MySql is not my cup of tea):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
    procedureName(s String)
BEGIN
    SELECT u.users_id 
    FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN mbrrole mr ON mr.member_id = u.users_id AND mr.ORGENTITY_ID 
    IN (
    SELECT ORGENTITY_ID FROM po_org_tree_v
    )
    INNER JOIN roledesc rd ON rd.role_id = mr.role_id 
    WHERE rd.displayname = s;
END
```

And you call this procedure like this :

```
WHERE u.firstname IS NOT NULL
AND (u.users_id in procedureName('Customer Service Representative') 
     OR u.users_id in procedureName('Account Representative'))
AND u.users_id in procedureName('Registered Customer');
```